# move virtual machine, subnet and vpn to a new account

Tags: azure, subscription

Is it possible to move a virtual machine, its subnet and VPN to a new azure account leaving all the rest in the previous azure account?
I already tried to copy the Virtual machine and the VPN but I cant set the same parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to raise a support request if it is possible, but usually, if you are trying to migrate between accounts you would need to migrate a whole subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Questions is very verge but a short answer will be;

Yes, it is possible but there are some limitation depending on your setup.

Please review article below.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources

Answer (score 0):

Could you move those resources to a new subscription and they transfer the ownership of that subscription to the new account?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-transfer